# Writing a recursive method that creates a random expression

Tags: java

I am supposed to write a recursive method for generating an expression in an expression tree. The method should have a parameter that limits the "height" of the expression tree. The maxHeight gives the maximum allowable height, not the actual height. The nodes for constants, variables, and binary operators have already been created but I am having issues getting the method to work. Below is the method that I have created and one of the tree nodes. I am still learning Java so please be kind. Any help will be appreciated.

```
static ExpNode randomExpression(int maxHeight) {
        ExpNode e1 = new BinOpNode('+', new VariableNode(), new ConstNode(maxHeight));
        ExpNode e2 = new BinOpNode('*', new ConstNode(maxHeight), new VariableNode());
        ExpNode e3 = new BinOpNode('*', e1, e2);
        ExpNode e4 = new BinOpNode('-', e1, new ConstNode(-3));
        if (maxHeight < 0) {
            return null;
        }
        if (maxHeight == 0) {           
            
            return new BinOpNode('-', e1, e2);
        } 
        if (maxHeight > 0) {            
            maxHeight++;
            return  new BinOpNode('/', e3, e4);
        }
        return randomExpression(maxHeight);
        
    }

static class BinOpNode extends ExpNode {
        char op;  // the operator, which must be '+', '-', '*', or '/'
        ExpNode left, right;  // the expression trees for the left and right operands.
        BinOpNode(char op, ExpNode left, ExpNode right) {
            if (op != '+' && op != '-' && op != '*' && op != '/')
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("'" + op + "' is not a legal operator.");
            this.op = op;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
        double value(double x) {
            double a = left.value(x);  // value of the left operand expression tree
            double b = right.value(x); // value of the right operand expression tree
            switch (op) {
            case '+': return a + b;
            case '-': return a - b;
            case '*': return a * b;
            default:  return a / b;
            }
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + left.toString() + op + right.toString() + ")";
        }
    }
      
    
        }
```

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of what "having issues getting the method to work" actually means? What part of the code do you have trouble with? What isn't working as you expect it? Does the code not compile? Do you get an error when you run it? Do you get a wrong result when you run it?

Comment: Hi @OHGODSPIDERS, the program is compelling without errors. The feedback that I received is that I must review that line "return randomExpression(maxHeight);" because it is not going to be executed and I am also increasing the value of maxHeight (a parameter) before a return sentence which has no effect.

Comment: In that case i don't quite know what more information you expect. That is a pretty specific feedback that already points out your exact errors. If you want a further tip on why that one return statement is never executed: Have a look at the if statements with return statements above like `if (maxHeight < 0)` and try to think of a value of `maxHeight` that would lead to your code reaching the line `return randomExpression(maxHeight);`

Comment: Thanks, @OHGODSPIDERS. I changed the one if statement to a for statement. It seems to be working alright.